# Diagonal swipe on snap vertical paging with iScroll 5 in iOS UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iscroll

I've implemented iScroll 5 with vertical snap paging for my app on iOS.
When I scroll in diagonal on iPad, the snap off iScroll lose position and take the native webview vertical scroll. The same happens when I scroll a little bit horizontal and then I scroll vertically. I can't prevent horizontal scroll because the UIWebView it's inside an UIScrollView with more UIWebView and if I prevent the UIWebView's scroll it block the scroll of the UIScrollView.

Someone know the solution?

This is my iScroll initialization code:

myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
                eventPassthrough: 'horizontal',
                scrollX: false,
                scrollY: true,
                momentum: false,
                snap:'.page',
                snapSpeed: 500,
                preventDefault: false,
                snapThreshold: .2,
                bounce: false,
                indicators: {
                    el: '#indicator',
                    resize: false
                }
            });

Thanks!